# QueryBuilder service is returning null object in CQ5/AEM

Tags: aem, query-builder

Hi I am trying to consume QueryBuilder service in other OSGI bundle in CQ5. But the queryBuilder object is returning null value. Can i get suggestion to consume it properly?

```
@Reference
private QueryBuilder queryBuilder;
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Reference` annotation will work only if you are specifying it in an OSGI Service. Can you confirm that its a class with `@Service` and `@Component` annotation on it?

```
//This is a component so it can provide or consume services
@Component

@Service
public class SearchServiceImpl implements SearchService {

/** Default log. */
protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

private Session session;

//Inject a Sling ResourceResolverFactory
@Reference
private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

@Reference
private QueryBuilder builder;
//---- Rest of your code

}
```

Refer to the implementation [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/using-query-builder-api.html).

Also if you are using `@Component` annotation on your class, you could goto `/system/console/components` and search for your class and look at the details, it will tell you if the dependencies are getting resolved and state of service.